# Crystal Reports - Tables Not Displaying Columns

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to use the database expert to select the data I want to display.  However, in some instances the table's columns are not being displayed.  Instead, only a single column - ID - is being shown, and it contains no data.

Is there any reason why this might be the case?

Comment: Have you used same datasource or datasource changed

Comment: This is the first time I've tried connecting to this datasource.  I can connect to and query some of the tables, but I cannot query others.  Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Few years back I have the same issue where I am able to connect to database but unable to see tables and when I traced out it supposed to be due to there is a configuration value in registery which is not allowing me to view tables and when I gave some big value I was able to view all tables... unfortunately I was unable to get that link but would suggest you to check the link for some of the registery values

Comment: Okay, thank you for that.  How can I change the value in the registery?  How do I know what value to change it to?

Comment: check this link http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1004707

Comment: Silva, thank you very much for your help.  Without you, I probably would have never solved that issue.

Comment: If necessary, is there a way I can restore the defaults in Regedit?

Comment: I would suggest to take the backup of the data that is already present in those registries and then revert back once your work is done...

Comment: Now are you able to see all the tables? shall I make it as answer?

Comment: Yes, please do. 

I already changed the data though.  I believe I changed maxrow in two folders because I thought it might fix the problem.

Comment: I am posting as answer so that others can use and also link will be saved for future reference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug but sometimes registery value will be less which prevents disappearing of tables.

Check below link which will show you the path to change registry.

[forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1004707](http://forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1004707)

I would suggest you to first take back up of the original data and then change the value.